Failed installation, could not detach loopback Ubuntu Server 22.04 LTS
Just trying to install Ubuntu Server on an old laptop and I am hit with the following error after installation. This occurs after the reboot now part of the installation after I remove the installation medium and press enter.
could not detach loopback /dev/loop3: device or resource busy
could not detach loopback /dev/loop2: device or resource busy 
could not detach loopback /dev/loop1: device or resource busy 
Unable to finalize remaining file systems, loop devices ignoring

